# What are the locations included in Quebec's vaccination passport law?

Tags: canada, covid-19, quebec

> On July 8, Quebec announced that they would introduce a vaccine
> passport by the fall — but would only use it to control access to
> locations like gyms, bars and restaurants if there is an outbreak.

https://globalnews.ca/news/8025474/canada-private-business-vaccine-passport/

There was an article about a vaccination passport being implemented in Quebec, but it didn't include an exhaustive list of the businesses that will require a vaccination passport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list has yet to be published, presumably because the legislation has yet to be finalised, but according to [this article](https://globalnews.ca/news/8099992/quebec-covid-vaccination-passport-update/) (posted yesterday, 10/08/21):

> Quebec will launch its COVID-19 vaccine passport system as of Sept. 1, Health Minister Christian Dubé announced Tuesday.
>
> With infections on the rise and an “inevitable fourth wave on the way,” Dubé laid out the details of the province’s plan, which will start with **gyms, bars, restaurants, festivals and events venues** across Quebec.
>
> The vaccine passport will only be used to access non-essential services, but **it will not be required for retail stores**. As for religious gatherings and weddings, Dubé said the government is still discussing whether or not to include them as events that will require the passport.

Answer (score 1):

There is no law regarding vaccination passports in Québec; therefore there is no exhaustive list of businesses that will require such a passport. [This](https://www.quebec.ca/en/health/health-issues/a-z/2019-coronavirus/progress-of-the-covid-19-vaccination/covid-19-vaccination-passport) is currently what the government has to say about the matter.